# MAX IF formula with range criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm facing a problem with trying to have max value with **multiple criteria**. The issue is that one criteria should be named range (TYPE) which contents will change. Data is numbers and text. Of course the whole formula is array formula.

```
=MAX(IF($C$2=$B$27:$B$509,IF($F7=$F$27:$F$509,IF($C$27:$C$509=TYPE,H$27:H$509)))
```

I tried to somehow implement OR function but it doesn't work properly. The thing with TYPE range is that it contains up to 3 text variables, user should be able to pick 3,2, or 1 of them and the order of these variables should be flexible. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT

My desired result in this case is 14%. I wish formula to search for max value only among types b, c (TYPE named range) but the result is 0%. The formula now looks like this:

```
=MAX(IF($G$4=$B$4:$B$20,IF($H4=$D$4:$D$20,IF($C$4:$C$20=TYPE,E$4:E$20))))
```

[image: sample data extract]

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected output for that data?

Comment: In addition to providing a small snippet of example data to illustrate the problem you are having and the expected out come you would like, you have a problem potentially with your if statement.  You never specify what you want done when the logical test is false.  You provide what to do with the true result, but you false result is not specified so it will default to displaying false.  I have an idea how to potentially solve this but I need to see your data layout first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this formula should work for you:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,($E$4:$E$15*($B$4:$B$15=$G$4)*($C$4:$C$15=$H$4)*(($D$4:$D$15=$G$8)+($D$4:$D$15=$G$9)+($D$4:$D$15=$G$10))),1)
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Functions used:

- [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)

Caveat:

- If a type in you data source is blank, and a type picked is also blank, then the data will be included as acceptable provided year and channel match as well.
- Excel 2010 or later.

Comment: Looks really good, thank you! However, I also need to find min value, but it seems that the formula will look quite different. In this scenario blank cells should be skipped and the result would be 5% (E7). Could you help me with this one?

Comment: Technically speaking this is a separate question and should be posted as such. I am pretty sure we can get something for you for the min option.  I would post a new question, state its a follow-up questions to this question and provide a link to this question.  In your question state basically state what you posted for a comment here.