# MIN IF formula with range criteria (follow-up)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question is a follow-up of this thread:
[MAX IF formula with range criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833486/max-if-formula-with-range-criteria)

In this case I need to find min value, but it seems that the formula will look quite different than in MAX variation in the post above. In this scenario blank cells should be skipped and the result would be 5% (E7). Could you help me with this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,($E$4:$E$15/((E4:E15<>"")*($B$4:$B$15=$G5)*($C$4:$C$15=$H5)*(($D$4:$D$15=$G$8)+($D$4:$D$15=$G$9)+($D$4:$D$15=$G$10)))),1)
```

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: This is great, worked perfectly! Thank you once again

Comment: @micxid If this answered your question you should mark it, so that future readers will notice that (and the answerer will gain rep)

Comment: @JBrazier you forgot to mention that micxid will also gain rep for awarding answers (not sure about upvoting) which will in turn allow micxid to have more privileges on the site